# Does anyone know what type of vine this is

Tags: vines

This is growing off of a very long vine in northern Indiana. It's in a shaded area so not too much light

[image][image]

Answer (score 4):

This appears to be the Smooth Carrion Flower (*[Smilax herbacea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smilax_herbacea)*). It is native to Eastern US and Canada. The leaf veins are very distinctive, starting at the petiole and running to the tip of the leaf, no main vein with branches. Found in forests and meadows close to water.

Comment: Are they edible?

Comment: I have never tried, but some interesting stories here: http://www.survivallandusa.com/Smilax-Herbacea-Carrion-Flower-Edible.html